# BigQuery transfer service: which file causes error?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to load around 1000 files from Google Cloud Storage into BigQuery using the BigQuery transfer service, but it appears I have an error in one of my files:

```
Job bqts_601e696e-0000-2ef0-812d-f403043921ec (table streams) failed with error INVALID_ARGUMENT: Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 19, but line starting at position:206 contains only 19 columns.; JobID: 931777629779:bqts_601e696e-0000-2ef0-812d-f403043921ec
```

How can I find which file is causing this error?
I feel like this is in the docs somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `bq show --format=prettyjson -j job_id_here` and will show a verbose error about the failed job. You can see more info about the usage of the command in [BigQuery managing jobs docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs#viewing_information_about_jobs).

I tried this with a failed job of mine wherein I'm loading csv files from a Google Coud Storage bucket in my project.

Command used:

```
bq show --format=prettyjson -j bqts_xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
```

Here is a snippet of the output. Output is in JSON format:
[image]

Comment: That was immensely helpful. For what is worth, I had issues with this command because it was searching for the job in the wrong location. Using `--location=<your job's location>` did the job, e.g. `--location=europe-west3`.